# How to count queryset from ManyToManyField in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    hot_league = models.ManyToManyField('HotLeague', blank=True)

class HotLeague(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    price_pool = models.IntegerField()
    winner = models.IntegerField()
```

In views:

```
match = Match.objects.filter(user=request.user)
hot_league = match.hot_league.filter(user=request.user).count()
```

Here in views `count()` is not working.
How can I count the `hot_league` which situated in `match` ??

Comment: Your `match` is not a *single* `match`. It is a `QuerySet` of `Match`es, and it may contain zero, one or more `Match` objects. That is why you can not do that.

Comment: And it's not `count()` that's not working, it's `hot_league` because `match` is a queryset not a Match instance.

Comment: How can I make `match` as a instance of `Match` and then use `hot_league = match.hot_league.filter(user=request.user).count()`...Is it possible??
@DanielRoseman Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `match` is *not* a `Match` object, it is a `QuerySet` that contains zero, one, or more `Match` objects. Therefore you can not use the `hot_league` relation on such `QuerySet`.

If you want to count all the `HotLeague`s that belong to the `request.user`, and have a `Match` that belongs to that `request.user` as well, you can count this as:

```
HotLeague.objects.filter(user=request.user, match__user=request.user).count()
```

This will count the *same* `HotLeague` multiple times if it belongs to multiple matches with `request.user` as `user`. If you wish to count each `HotLeague` only once, you can add a [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to it:

```
HotLeague.objects.filter(user=request.user, match__user=request.user).distinct().count()
```

Or you can annotate the number the `Match`es with the number of `HotLeague`s by that user, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

matches = Match.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(
    nhotleagues=Count('hotleague', filter=Q(hotleague__user=request.user))
)
```

Each `Match` that originates from this queryset, will have an extra attribute `nhotleagues` that specifies the number of `HotLeague`s of that user. So you can render this like:

```
{% for match in matches %}
    {{ match.pk }}: {{ match.notleagues }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

You can sum up counts, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

matches = Match.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(
    total=Count('hotleague', distinct=True, filter=Q(hotleague__user=request.user)) +
          Count('mega_league', distinct=True, filter=Q(megaleague__user=request.user)) +
          Count('head_to_head_league', distinct=True, filter=Q(head_to_head_league__user=request.user))
)
```

Although of course, the more tables you add in a JOIN, the more expensive the query will be.

Comment: It's so close. But have a problem. `Match` objects has many `QuerySet`. When I use `for` loop using `match` in template then every `QuerySet` of `HotLeague` count number remain same for all `Match` though all `user` select `Match` but not select `hot_league`..

Comment: @jhonarab: then you probably should annotate your queryset, see edit.

Comment: Now it's working...But I also have some other fields like `hot_league` in `Match` objects. That means I have, `mega_league`, `ex_league` like more..How can I also count these like your way and sum everything then render..
`match = Match.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(
        hotleagues=Count('hot_league', filter=Q(hot_league__user=request.user)),
        megaleagues=Count('mega_league', filter=Q(mega_league__user=request.user)),
        exleagues=Count('ex_league', filter=Q(head_to_head_league__user=request.user)),
    )` is not working..
in template how can i sum all??

Comment: @jhonarab: you can add `distinct=True` to your count, so `Count('hot_league, distinct=True, filter=Q(...))'`.

Comment: then how sum these three and render it in template?

Comment: @jhonarab: you just annotate your queryset, and render it with `{{ match.hotleagues }}`, `{{ hot.megaleagues }}`, etc.

Comment: No sir, I need to render the sum of all these. how?

Comment: @jhonarab: ah, you can annotate the sum, so `.annotate(total=Count(..) + Count(..) + Count(..))`, and then render the `{{ match.total }}`.

Comment: aha, finally it's working what i want...Thank you so much Sir..!!